# What is the most rigorous book for knot theory?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, knot-theory

I have read the knot book by Colin Adams and it has been very helpful with getting to grips with the basics. I struggle with showing things and proving things. 
I need a book with a lot of rigorous proofs.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Knots, by G. Burde and H. Zieschang, de Gruyter Stud. Math., vol. 5, Walter de Gruyter, New York, 2003.

Comment: While jammarqz is correct, you might find An Introduction to Knot Theory by Lickorish (http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-98254-0) more accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I understand the basic stuff but I would struggle to answer something like "prove invariance of colouring numbers with respect to Reidemeister moves R2". I suppose I also need a book with lots of questions like these and answers. (My teacher doesnt hand out answers )

Comment: Rolfsen is a must for anyone who is really going to study knot theory.